# Weird behavior on checkboxes in angular 1.2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

In Angular 1.0, having two checkboxes with the same name and different true values would correctly cause the checkbox to have the right value.

In Angular 1.2 this behavior seems to have changed completely but with no documentation.

Here is my angular 1.0 good example
http://jsfiddle.net/rpTen/248/

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="Ctrl">

  userType: <input name="input" ng-model="userType" required type='checkbox' ng-true-value='2'>

 <input name="input" ng-model="userType" required type='checkbox' ng-true-value='3'>

 <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">Required</span><br>
 <tt>userType = {{userType}}</tt><br>
 <tt>myForm.input.$valid = {{myForm.input.$valid}}</tt><br>
 <tt>myForm.input.$error = {{myForm.input.$error}}</tt><br>
          <tt>myForm.input.$dirty = {{myForm.input.$dirty}}</tt><br>
 <tt>myForm.$valid = {{myForm.$valid}}</tt><br>
 <tt>myForm.$error.REQUIRED = {{!!myForm.$error.REQUIRED}}</tt><br>
</form>
```

here is the same example but updating to 1.2
http://jsfiddle.net/rpTen/247/

Comment: why would you have 2 form controls with same name in one form in the first place? `ng-model` can be the same but `name` makes no sense

Comment: Technically it is valid html, but I see what you are saying. I changed the name and it didn't solve the underlying issue.